# ggplot2 - add elements programmatically

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have built a wrapper for ggplot, and would like to enable the user of this to turn on or off certain elements. For example, in some plots the user will want to set the y-axis minimum to 0, while in others they will not.

What I want to be able to do, in this case, is have the user pass the 'ymin' variable to the function as T or F. If T, then the following element should be added to the chart.

```
+ expand_limits(y=0)
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this? Or is there an entirely different approach to this kind of problem that I should be using?

Comment: There is - you can use an `if` loop. What have you tried? (note - you can save a ggplot as an object, e.g. `p <- ggplot(...) + ...` and then do `p + expand_limits(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

mathematical.coffee has pushed me in the right direction. Here is an elaborated answer.

```
plot <- ggplot(data=data, aes(...))+
   geom_line()

if(ymin == T)
{
  plot <- plot + expand_limits(y=0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrapp the your ggplot in a function, where you parameter are optionally. If no parameter are provided to the function, the assigned value in the signature is used

```
plotWithLimits <- function(y=0, data, ...) {
  return ggplot(data=data, aes(..)) + geom_line()+expand_limits(y=0)
}
```